# Nuance of 「～なくても仕方ない」

Tags: meaning, nuances

I came across the following sentence:

> 「私の技が未熟なうちは**伝わらなくても仕方ない**と思っています」

I understood 「**伝わらなくても仕方ない**」 more or less as the need to carry out the action determined by the relevant verb (伝わる); however,  I was wondering whether 「**伝わらなくても仕方ない**」 carries the nuance of (or maybe even non of the ones listed below):

a) "one is obliged to do so"

b) "it is better to do so"

c) "it is of no use not to"

If my general understanding of this phrase is wrong, please let me know. Besides, it is the first time I came across this construction, so I want to know whether native-speakers would concern this "pattern" common.

Comment: What makes you think it has those nuances?

Comment: I tried to find the construction in others contexts by using google; however I only found examples with non-negative verb form preceding 仕方ない (https://nayami.shiawasehp.net/kangaenai.html / https://counseling-restart.com/vain/). The first one sounds to me as if “there is no use” of thinking about X not that somebody can’t do anything about it. I then tried to “reverse” the meaning onto the negative here.

Comment: Wait, I think the examples are not correct. I've just realised that the construction in these examples are different from the one in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understood 「伝わらなくても仕方ない」 more or less as the need to carry out the action determined by the relevant verb (伝わる)

It doesn't mean that, it means "there is nothing I can do about the fact that it is not transmitted".

> 私の技が未熟なうちは伝わらなくても仕方ないと思っています

This means "I realise that while my skill is still immature/undeveloped, there is nothing I can do about the fact that (something) is not transmitted." I am not sure of the context so I have no idea what 伝わる refers to here, it probably doesn't translate as "transmitted".

> If my general understanding of this phrase is wrong, please let me know.

I've tried to do that.

> Besides, it is the first time I came across this construction, so I want to know whether native-speakers would concern this "pattern" common.

Verb-なくてもしかたない is a common pattern in Japanese.